# automatic layout adjustment to varying browser window size

Tags: apache-flex, layout, rows, mxml, screen-resolution

In Flex4/mxml, I have a bunch of elements like TextFields, Buttons or anything else. I want to place them horizontally next to each other. But for cases where the browser window or screen resolution is too small such that not all of them fit horizontally, I want a layout which automatically shifts the superfluous elements to the row below.
In other words, I need a layout which comprises both, horizontal and vertical layouting, whereas horizontal has priority over vertical. So actually a very simple layout, yet I'm unable to find a solution. How can I achieve that?

For example, the following is a starting point:

```
<mx:HBox horizontalGap="0" width="{width-30}" horizontalAlign="center" textAlign="center">
    <mx:Label paddingLeft="10" text="anytext1" />                
    <mx:Label id="warn12" text="anytext2" />
    <mx:Button label="Do Something1" click="{cf.doSomething(1)}"/>
    <mx:Label paddingLeft="0" text="anytext3" />
    <mx:Button label="Do Something2" click="{cf.doSomething(2)}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

The HBox places all Labels and Buttons next to each other horizontally, and if the screen size is too small, the right most items exceed the right screen border, but I want them to appear below on the left in a second row.

In addition, but less important, I want the Labels and Buttons to be centered if the screen size is bigger than necessary. That's what the horizontalAlign="center" and textAlign="center" are meant for.

Comment: What I'm looking for is so simple that I don't know what else to explain. Maybe I'm missing such a layout in Flex4, but I could not find. There is a similar question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763061/flex-container-automatic-layout?rq=1], but the answers are outdated.

Comment: Are you able to use Spark components in your project?

Comment: Yes, I can use also spark.

Comment: I posted a discussion about this [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292081/duplicates-of-questions-that-only-have-a-link-only-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `Tile` element.  It automatically wraps elements to a new line if the screen isn't wide enough to accommodate everything:

```
<mx:Tile id="myFlow" 
        direction="horizontal" width="{width-30}"
        paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0" 
        paddingRight="0" paddingLeft="0" 
        verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0">
    <mx:Label paddingLeft="10" text="anytext1" />                
    <mx:Label id="warn12" text="anytext2" />
    <mx:Button label="Do Something1" click="{cf.doSomething(1)}"/>
    <mx:Label paddingLeft="0" text="anytext3" />
    <mx:Button label="Do Something2" click="{cf.doSomething(2)}"/>
</mx:Tile>
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, this answers the main part of my question. But in this solution all elements are assigned the same with, which is the with of the broadest element. Is there a way to handle different widths too? And is it also possible to have centered alignment within each row? (see second part of my question)

Comment: @HorstP Ah, interesting twist. That's definitely worth posting as a separate question.

Comment: Ok, I will post a separate question for this.